# Selecting multiple groups in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one dropdown which consists of list of groups and respective items for the groups.I want to select a group so that automatically the groups items should also select based on the selection of groups in the dropdown

Here is my html code :

```
<select id="example-multiple-optgroups" class="multiselect-group">
            <optgroup label="Group 1">
                <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
                <option value="1-2" selected="selected">Option 1.2</option>
                <option value="1-3" selected="selected">Option 1.3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 2">
                <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
                <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
                <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
            </optgroup>
</select
```

And JavaScript:

```
 $('.multiselect-group').before('<input type="checkbox" />');
$(document).on('click', '.multiselect-group', function(event) {
    var checkAll = true;
    var $opts = $(this).parent().nextUntil(':has(.multiselect-group)'); 
    var $inactive = $opts.filter(':not(.active)'); 
    var $toggleMe = $inactive;
    if ($inactive.length == 0) { 
        $toggleMe = $opts;
        checkAll = false;
    }
    $toggleMe.find('input').click();
    $(this).parent().find('input').attr('checked', checkAll);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am trying these code ,but I am not getting the proper output,please let me know procedure to get this done.

Comment: `I want to select a group so that automatically the groups items should also select based on the selection of groups in the dropdown` what does this mean? can you explain properly?

Comment: Instead of using a select. Use 2 listbox with group titles in one and another having the group items.

Comment: by selecting one of the optgroup like Group 1 in my code ,it has to select all the options with in the group like option 1.1,1.2,1.3 has to select based on the group

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [plugin](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#with-optgroups) and below is the code. To download js and css file please [Click Here](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#with-optgroups)
Image is attached [image]

```
    <head>
    <link href="css/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select multiple="multiple">        

        <optgroup label="Group 1">
                <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
                <option value="1-2" >Option 1.2</option>
                <option value="1-3" >Option 1.3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 2">
                <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
                <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
                <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
            </optgroup>

    </select>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/multiple-select.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("select").multipleSelect({
            multiple: true,
            multipleWidth: 100,
            width: '100%'
        });
    </script>
</body>
```